# How to control speech output on Bixby

Tags: text-to-speech, speech, bixby, bixbystudio

I'm using Bixby Developer studio and I have my UI output created and it works. How do I create or control speech output?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Bixby will automatically read the text in the UI - if that is sufficient, you are set. (Be careful here - In good VUX design, UI text and speech text are typically different. UI text is often longer, speech text often shorter and more expressive).

To have speech different from the UI text, you should set the speech key of a template in a dialog. You can use all of the features of dialog like Bixby EL language here.

Comment: Are there any plans to add SSML support to give more control over the responses?

Comment: Ben - definitely a desired feature. Please upvote that feature request - https://support.bixbydevelopers.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/360024921673-Support-SSML

Answer (score 1):

Update: Bixby now supports SSML

https://bixbydevelopers.com/dev/docs/reference/type/template.speech

Comment: only the <lang> and <voice> tags right now but much more is coming.