# How to keep spoken output, followup question, and rendered content independent?

Tags: bixby

I am trying to render a result-view where there is 1) spoken output; 2) a different text summary of that output; and 3) A spoken followup prompt.

I would like the followup prompt (obviously) to be spoken after the spoken output. But I don't want it, or the spoken output, to be rendered to the screen.

I've tried the following result-view:

```
result-view {
  match: myStructure (this)
  message ("#{value (this.spokenResponse)}") 


  render {
    layout-match (this.spokenResponseSummary) {
      mode (Details)
    }
  }

  followup {
    prompt {
      dialog (Would you like to hear more?)
      on-confirm {
        message ("#{value (this.details)}")
      }
      on-deny {
        message (Okay.)
      }
    }
  }
  conversation-drivers {
    conversation-driver {
        template ("More Details")
      }
    }
  }
```

This renders the spokenResponseSummary - that's good!

But it also displays the spokenResponse + followup prompt at the top of the screen, and the spokenResponseSummary below.

How to I *not* display the spokenResponse + followup prompt. (Ideally, how to do I display some arbitrary text at the top of the screen, in its place?)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the `speech` key to have Bixby read our different dialog than what is shown.

```
result-view {
  match: MyModel(this)
  message {
    template ("I am shown.") {
      speech ("I am read out loud.")
    }
  }
  ... your content here ...
}
```

https://bixbydevelopers.com/dev/docs/reference/type/template.speech

More details here:
[How to control speech output on Bixby](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54445988/how-to-control-speech-output-on-bixby)

Comment: Thank you. I think I figured out that I need to use a dialog in addition to result view. (I don't think a `speech` is a valid key for result-view.) I still don't see how to speak, but not display, the followup prompt. Just moving the followup prompt to spokenResponse (and leaving the prompt blank, e.g., `followup { prompt { dialog () }}` ) seems to break the actual follow up functionality

Comment: `speech` is not a key of `result-view`. it's a key in any `template`.

Comment: Added an example.