# SSML support for Bixby

Tags: bixby

We have a zip code "94582" which is being pronounced "Ninety four thousand five hundred eighty two". Is it possible to have it pronounced as "Nine Four Five Eight Two" in bixby?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As an update to the previous answer: Bixby now supports SSML

https://bixbydevelopers.com/dev/docs/reference/type/template.speech

Answer (score 2):

While there is no SSML support in Bixby at this time, we can define an optional speech channel.

```
template("This gets read.") {
   speech("This is spoken.")
}
```

https://bixbydevelopers.com/dev/docs/reference/type/template.speech

[How to control speech output on Bixby](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54445988/how-to-control-speech-output-on-bixby)

Comment: Currently there is no built-in sneaky way to change the speech if  property zip is "94582", however, if in your JS, you can create a property zipSpeech to hold the text as "9 4 5 8 2", then template(zip) and speech(zipSpeech) would display text as "94582" but speech would be digit by digit.

Comment: Thanks @BixbyDevSupport-Tokonyan, this was useful to know. : )